# Positive Photo Resist for lift-off & Negative for EBL?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, integrated-circuit

I would like to know two things about Photo Resists (PR):

1. How is positive photo resist used for lift-off?
2. What is EBL and why negative photo resist is used in this case?

Comment: Wow, why 4 up votes?  This question lacks effort.  Lift off is placing metal down after the PR is developed.  The metal is placed everywhere and is then "lifted off" when the PR is removed. EBL is obviously the Elite Baseball League.  I'm guessing they don't want negative photo's because that would be bad publicity and hence the use of negative photo resist.   :^)

Comment: You must be funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear up some terminology here for the benefit of the reader.

A positive photo resist is one in which the exposed areas are removed in subsequent processing steps. i.e. where ever the light shines, the photoresist (PR) is removed.

EBL means Electron Beam Lithography.

---

In lift off, you are depositing a layer of material on top of a PR layer, there is subsequent processing that removes the PR and in that process "lifts off" the deposited material along with the PR.  In places where the PR does not exist the deposited material adheres to the exposed areas and remains after the PR processing.

In EBL your patterning is through electrons, and when the electrons impact the PR they cross-link the polymer making it harder.  That means in areas where the beam contacts (is exposed) the PR stays behind.  It is possible to make a Positive EBL resist but the mechanism for exposure is one of damage to sensitize to subsequent processing.  This is difficult to do without also damaging the substrate.